# MongoDB querying: possible to sort by a list of values?

Tags: sorting, mongodb

I doubt this is currently possible with MongoDB, but I'd like to know if a
query's result set can be sorted by an array of values within that
result set.  This would be analogous to MySQL's "ORDER BY FIELD"
functionality.  A quick example of this MySQL functionality:
http://pastebin.com/qtL1vKcM

Here is a similar example of what I'm trying to accomplish in the
mongodb console: http://pastebin.com/LuKqA6b1

I know what most folks would suggest: do the sorting in the client
side/application code.  However, it's not doable in my case. I'm
paginating the result set (ie. the skip()/limit() combo).  Sorting in
the application code would require selecting the entire collection
into my application code, unfiltered, sorting it, and then applying
the pagination.

I need to sort the result set before applying the skip()/limit().

I think this functionality would be extremely practical.  In my case,
I'm attempting to integrate [Sphinx text search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) functionality with
MongoDB, while maintaining Sphinx's sorting by match relevancy.  It
works like this:

1. Sphinx docs are stored with a MongoID as a string attribute.  This
   directly corresponds to a MongoDB document.
2. When a user text search is performed, Sphinx is queried first.  The
   MongoID's from the Sphinx result set are then used to query MongoDB
   collection (ie. the $in operator).
3. The relevancy sorting provided by the Sphinx result set is lost.
4. :(

Is there any practical way to accomplish this?

Comment: You haven't read any books and documentation about MongoDB right?

Comment: @ahmet: i guess you haven't read question properly...

Comment: What I mean is that's not possible and it is said in many books etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, but i guess that you can return paged result from sphinx, load appropriate data from mongodb using `$in` operator and then sort on client side paged result according to sphinx id's sorting. Seems this should work for you.

Mongodb guys for sure thinking about 'real' full text search support(there is even planned [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-380) feature), and i guess it will be soon (probably at this year).

Comment: This is definitely the best solution.  Although its necessary to always have the documents in Sphinx and MongoDB completely in sync.  I'm running into fragmented results when a document exists in Sphinx but not in the MongoDB coollection.

Comment: @TimboWhite: So your writes to mongodb and sphinx going asynch? I just wondering, because of i am also planning mongodb and sphinx integration in the way you described in your question ;)

Comment: I haven't pinpointed it yet, but it's probably some cronjob that archives data.  My guess is it's deleting from mongo but not sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible and there are no straightforward workarounds either.